# How to access JSON response in Swift using AWS API Gateway-generated iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a working REST API based on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html) API Gateway tutorial. I'm able to successfully invoke it via the test functionality of the AWS Console; and I'm able to successfully invoke it via my simple iOS Swift 4.2 Xcode application using the iPhone XR simulator.

I know it's working via a real, live external call because I can see the Cloudwatch logs which always register a 200 response and is sending the results back to the Client.

My problem is really in understanding the Swift code, and I'm hoping that a Swift expert can help me understand how to unpack `result` in the code below.

Here's my code in ViewController.swift for invoking the REST API and attempting to print `result` to the console:

```
@IBAction func userInvokeApi(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("You clicked invoke api...")
    let client = SVTLambdaGateClient.default()
    client.calcGet(operand2: "3", _operator: "+", operand1: "5").continueWith{ (task: AWSTask?) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task?.error {
            print("Error occurred: \(error)")
            return nil
        }

        if let result = task?.result {
            // Do something with result
            print("The result is... \(result)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

As pointed out in the comments below, I'm getting the following result because it's printing out the address of the object:

```
You clicked invoke api...
The result is... <AmplifyRestApiTest.Empty: 0x600002020770> {
}
```

(where `AmplifyRestApiTest` is the name of my Xcode project.)

**UPDATE** When I set a breakpoint on the `print` statement, this is what I see in the Debug pane:

[image: Screenshot of debug pane showing trace at breakpoint at print statement.]

**UPDATE 2**
When I type `task?.result` there are two viable properties [as per this answer from the Amplify team](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1389#issuecomment-480059767): `error` and `result`. So, since my API responds successfully I am assuming I just don't know how to view `result`.

Can someone help me understand what steps I must take to access members of this class object?

Here is the corresponding method in the API Gateway-generated iOS Swift SDK code:

```
/*
 @param operand2 
 @param _operator 
 @param operand1 

 return type: Empty
 */
public func calcGet(operand2: String, _operator: String, operand1: String) -> AWSTask<Empty> {
    let headerParameters = [
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Accept": "application/json",

            ]

    var queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]
    queryParameters["operand2"] = operand2
    queryParameters["operator"] = _operator
    queryParameters["operand1"] = operand1

    let pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

    return self.invokeHTTPRequest("GET", urlString: "/calc", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: nil, responseClass: Empty.self) as! AWSTask<Empty>
}
```

I'm fairly certain this return type of `Empty` refers to the `Empty` model defined for the REST API as shown in the screenshot below. I think it's "empty" because the API doesn't alter the response from the Lambda function back to the Client. So, it's all pass-through. Indeed, the tutorial explains that the other models -- Output and Result -- are not used because it "relies on the passthrough behavior and does not use this model."

Any thoughts?

[image: API Gateway screenshot showing Empty model]

Comment: You could try `print(String(bytes: result, encoding: .utf8)!)`

Comment: Thanks Don. Unfortunately, when I use that construct I get the following error message: `Argument type 'Empty' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'`. Which I don't really understand..

Comment: have you tried 
  if let result = task?.result {
            // Do something with result
            print("The result is... \(result.anyProprty from Empty class?)")
        }

Comment: you are actually printing a class object which always prints address for object when you print something  like print(result.title) you may find a value

Comment: You are absolutely right, @AbuUlHassan... and I've come to realize `result` is a class object. My problem is that I don't know what the properties of the `Empty` class are. I'm fairly certain that the AWS Lambda function returns a result to API Gateway with the following vars `{a, b, op, c}`, where `a` and `b` are the operands; `op` is the operator, and `c` is the result. And API Gateway passes it through as JSON. AWSTask<Empty> must be defined in one of the POD files but I can't find it.

Comment: I should add -- `result.c` yields an error saying result "has no member c". Incidentally, I tried to list the properties using let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: Empty()) and then print(mirror.children.compactMap { $0.label }) but this printed out ["some"] ???

Comment: place a breakpoint at print("The result is... \(result)") 
now in console  write        po result   and press escape button it will show you some possible properties or function go with all of them one by one you will probably find something go worth.

Comment: Thank you @AbuUlHassan! I just added a screenshot of the breakpoint results to my question. When I expand `result` it shows me, I think, that I need to look at the AWSCore pod file. I don't understand what you're suggesting by pressing the escape button.. but I will google and try to figure out what you mean.

Comment: by pressing escape button it shows possible properties and functions you can use with that object sorry for late i was just taking some off days.

Comment: Thanks again @AbuUlHassan. I just updated my question above with a screenshot of what I see when I hit the escape key directly after `result`. I also googled the use of the escape key in Xcode, but somehow couldn't find a good source explaining it's usage. Either way, I don't see how this helps me because it just seems to tell me what I already know: that `result` is of type `Empty`. It doesn't seem to tell me anything about the object itself in terms of properties. Also, it's a long list to scroll of seemingly unrelated things.

Comment: can u upload you sample project somewhere ? so i can download and tell what actually result contains. 
because after typing "result." and pressing escape key shows you intellisense for possible properties and functions for result

Comment: I appreciate the offer but my simple project does involve some configuration, as I'm using the AWS iOS SDK (maintained by AWS Amplify) and it has to make a live REST API call to AWS API Gateway. When I type `task?.result` there are two viable properties [as per this answer from the Amplify team](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1389#issuecomment-480059767): `error` and `result`. So, since my API responds successfully I am assuming I just don't know how to view `result`.

Comment: i am once again suggesting you write "task?.result." and then press escape button or press CTRL+Space button it will show some possible function properties that can be used ...

Comment: When I type `task?.result` and press escape or control-spacebar, the only option I see is `Empty? result`. I think I'm correctly accessing the REST API returned response... but I don't know how to see the contents. In other words, I don't know how to see the value represented by `task?.result`. At least, that's my guess. (Yes, I'm still stuck!)

Comment: I'm a bit late, but did you find a solution to this?